# How to change UI Button in WPF using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, button, mvvm

With the `Import` button, I used :

```
<Button Command="{Binding ImportCommand}"
        Content="Import"
        Margin="5"
        Width="100"></Button>
```

I disable `Cap Nhat` button if in `Ma nhan su` textbox and `Ho Ten` textbox was false. I used :

```
<Button Command="{Binding EditCommand}"
        Content="Cập nhật"
        Margin="5"
        Width="100">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
             <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), ElementName=Text1}"
                               Value="True">
                      <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                              Value="False"></Setter>
                  </DataTrigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
     </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Everything worked OK!, but in UI `Cap nhat` button was changed, I want to change UI `Cap nhat` button like `Import` button.
Thank all for your help

[image: UI different 2 button]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to base the style on the style that is applied to the "Import" button:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
```

Or set the `IsHitTestVisible` property instead of `IsEnabled`:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), ElementName=Text1}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
</DataTrigger>
```